# Haskell daemon fails to pull from Redis with `getAddrInfo` / `Too many open files` errors

Tags: haskell, redis, daemon

I have a relatively simple Haskell daemon that `blpop`s things from Redis and writes them to a channel in one thread, and reads them from the channel and prints them to stdout in another.

On running it, it starts off fine, then after some time, I get the following on `stderr`:

```
hogstash: getAddrInfo: does not exist (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

and see the following in my `system.log` (OSX):

```
hogstash[11281]: dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files)
```

I'd infer from this that somehow I'm doing some unbounded-threaded-DNS lookups, but I don't understand how, and I have insufficient familiarity with Haskell to really get how to debug this.

The main program is as follows:

```
import Hogstash.Inputs.Redis
import Hogstash.Event
import Hogstash.Outputs.Stdout

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.BoundedChan
import Control.Monad

main = forever $ do
           channel <- newBoundedChan 10
           forkIO $ do
               connection <- tmpHaxx
               forever $ getEvent connection "logstash:beaver" channel
           forkIO $ forever $ stdout channel
```

`stdout` is simply:

```
module Hogstash.Outputs.Stdout where

import Control.Concurrent.BoundedChan as BC
import Hogstash.Event

stdout :: BoundedChan Event -> IO ()
stdout channel = do 
                     event <- readChan channel
                     putStrLn $ show event
```

and `getEvent` is:

```
module Hogstash.Inputs.Redis where

import Database.Redis

import Hogstash.Event

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.BoundedChan as BC
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC


eventFromByteString :: BSC.ByteString -> Event
eventFromByteString _ = Event

listListen key = blpop [key] 0

tmpHaxx = connect defaultConnectInfo -- FIXME Remove this

getEvent :: Connection -> String -> BoundedChan Event -> IO ()

getEvent a b = getEvent' a (BSC.pack b)

getEvent' ci key channel = do
                                fnar <- pullEvent ci key
                                case fnar of
                                    Just e -> BC.writeChan channel e
                                    Nothing -> return ()

pullEvent :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO (Maybe Event)
pullEvent connection key = do
                                    event_data <- runRedis connection $ listListen key
                                    return (case event_data of
                                        Left a -> Nothing
                                        Right a -> extractEvent a)

extractEvent :: Maybe (a, BSC.ByteString) -> Maybe Event
extractEvent = fmap (eventFromByteString . snd)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With many thanks to `Kaini` from `#haskell` on Freenode:

`main` was using `forever` in a foolish attempt to block the main thread indefinitely. This of course meant forever spawning Redis and stdout threads, hence hitting file open limits.

Rewriting `main` as

```
main = do
           channel <- newBoundedChan 10
           forkIO $ do
               connection <- tmpHaxx
               forever $ getEvent connection "logstash:beaver" channel
           forkIO $ forever $ stdout channel
           forever $ threadDelay 1000 -- Block forever
```

worked significantly better!

Comment: To get rid of the artificial `forever $ threadDelay 1000`, consider moving the connection or stdout thread to the main thread, or, if you need more sophisticated error handling, look at something like `race` from Control.Concurrent.Async.

Comment: The final architecture will look a bit different (I'm going to have multiple input and output threads, as per Logstash, which I'm cloning) but cheers for the heads up - I was planning to `takeMVar` for a sort-of-shutdown-hook as suggested by `merijn` from `#haskell`, but I'll look at `race` - thanks!

Comment: The trouble is that you have to do exception handling by hand, since if your thread throws an exception, the main thread will block forever. Control.Concurrent.Async tries to handle things like error propagation between threads for you to avoid the issues associated with manipulating MVars by hand.

Comment: Ah, yes, I need to re-read the bit of Conc&ParHaskell about Exceptions - thanks for the warning